# Convert mongoid aggregated result to ruby object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, hash, mongoid

I am querying a Model in Rails using mongoid

```
product1 = Products.where(list_id: params[:list_id])

@records = product1.collection.aggregate([
                  { "$match": { "rowdatas.field_value": {"$regex": params[:search], "$options": "i"} }},
                  { "$sort": { "rowdatas.field_name": 1 , "rowdatas.field_value": 1  } }
              ])
```

After the results are retrieved in @records , their class is Mongoid Collection View. This is practically unusable since its not a Ruby object. How do I use it like a regular object that can be iterated , paginated similar to a mongoid criteria object (like product1).

Comment: Isn't [`Mongo::Collection::View`](http://api.mongodb.com/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection/View.html) an `Enumerable`? That would mean that you can use all the usual things like `each`, `map`, ... on it, no?

Comment: Yes but I could not find a way to convert it to a standard Mongoid:Criteria object on which I can append paginate methods from gems like will_pagniate.

Comment: Haven't used MongoDB for awhile but you might need to do it by hand by manually adding pagination to the aggregation. Are you sure you need to use the aggregation stuff for this query? Normal `where` queries should support regexes.

Comment: As basically stated by @muistooshort, there is no reason why what you have listed in the question cannot be a simple query. If you must use an aggregation pipeline then you use the [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) and [`$skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) pipeline stages instead of the cursor methods. That's how you "paginate" an aggregation result in all drivers.

Comment: I am also having same problem. Is there any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use Mongoid::Document#instantiate method.

```rb
product1 = Products.where(list_id: params[:list_id])

@records = product1.collection.aggregate([
                  { "$match": { "rowdatas.field_value": {"$regex": params[:search], "$options": "i"} }},
                  { "$sort": { "rowdatas.field_name": 1 , "rowdatas.field_value": 1  } }
              ]).map{|product_attributes| Product.instantiate(product_attributes)}
```

Make sure you use $limit and $skip to paginate your results.